# disable <li> tag with session

Tags: php, disable-link

i have drop-down menu & my site enable for all people to  the enter

but i don't have idea about how to disable it when not authorizes users enter to site

i know to disable button with specific users like :

```
<input type="submit" value="Click Here" <?php if($this_user != 6 and $this_user != 1) { ?> disabled="disabled" <?php } ?>>
```

i want do it in this tag

```
<li><a href="newsubject">New Projects</a></li>
```

and my session code in same page is:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if($_SESSION['valid_user'])
{
?>
```

and the end of html page like

```
<?php
}
else
{
echo  "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>";
}
?>
```

thanks for help me ...

Comment: I think you'll need to use the `isset()` function in your

if( isset($_SESSION['valid_user']) code to get a true/false to be returned and the properly logic to work.

Comment: You should use permission manager kind of thing, with user levels defined

Comment: @Newbi3 are you say like if($_SESSION['valid_user'])
{
 $this_user = $_SESSION['valid_user'];

Comment: Look at @Ravi's code. In your example inside the if statement, it needs a boolean value so true/false. if($_SESSION['valid_user']) does not return a boolean, it will likely return a string or null which will break your code

Comment: Null or empty string are treated as false in an if statement.

Comment: @KaarelNummert I stand corrected. I still consider it bad style/practice as you don't know what is in that value and might be tempted to reference it while it could be null.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can disable an anchor element (`<a .... >`). Instead strip the link of the anchor element if it should be disabled. Like so:

```
<?php
if($this_user == 6 and $this_user == 1) {
?>
<li><a href="newsubject">New Projects</a></li>
<?
} else {
?>
<li>New Projects</li>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for try help me ... but the link still enable for all users . i cant understand your answer.please complete it

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change href attribute of link tag.

use below code to disable a tag is not valid use. this will show the link but user will not able to click if not valid user...

```
<?php
    $href="#";
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])){
    $href="newsubject";
    }
?>

    <li><a href="<?php echo $href ?>">New Projects</a></li>
```

Comment: thanks for try help me ... but the link still enable for all users

Comment: do you want to hide this link if not valid user?

Comment: i have users table in my db and i uses by id- if id for user =1,2,3 ok he is can open link , but the user id is 4,5 no he is cant open this link

Comment: in what variable your are checking user_id?

Comment: $valid_user <-- this variable

Comment: `$allowed_users=array(1,2,3); 
$href="#";
if(in_array($valid_user,$allowed_users){
 $href="newsubject";
}`
then close php and code your li tag with a tag as in answer